# Specifying individual CustomField in package.xml (vscode) does not deploy to Org, but when retrieving by object it does?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, sfdx-plugin, package.xml

When retrieving CustomFields in package.xml by specifying:

```
<types>
  <members>ObjectName.FieldName__c</members>
  <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
```

They retrieve fine but when right clicking on them in VSCode after connecting to another Org and clicking Deploy to Source does not work - nothing happens and no errors or anything.

If I change my package.xml file to:

```
<types>
  <members>SameObjectName</members>
  <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

And then I repeat the above process, it works fine and deploys - is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you use workbench to make sure this is not happening there as well? I am trying to triage this to say its extension pack bug or CLI bug versus API bug! Also please  list which API version and version of your extension pack

Comment: FWIW this exact behavior is what stopped my company from moving from Ant to DX for (sandbox-based) deployments & source control about 2 yrs ago.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava If you right click package.xml and click 'Deploy Source in Manifest to Org' it works fine.... the problem is if you right click on an individual object in the tree and tell it to deploy on its own. I also reproduced this on Linux VSCode - can you try? Thanks

Comment: @realtek Can you add the output you see in output panel in your vscode?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava When reproducing the issue there is no output, log or any activity. Its like nothing happens at all. I see you work for Salesforce, happy to reach out directly if you need a screenshare or something.

Comment: Email me at mohith.shrivastava@salesforce.com

Comment: Any updates here by chance, fellas?